# Blender moving bij +n actually moves by +n.nnnn

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to move a point in blender on the x-axis and typed g x .4. The current coordinate was 1;0;0 and became 1.444;0;0 instead of 1.4;0;0.
Then I tried to check if the increments were the problem, which they were... When I tried to move a point on x: 1 by increment, it jumped to 1.95238 instead of 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the coordinates set on local instead of global, that explains all.